# How to update one layer at a time in a GEE app

Tags: google-earth-engine

I use a GEE app to visualize operational model output (so, it updates daily). The app displays about 10 gridded layers, and I have added checkboxes to easily allow the user to turn on / off layers of interest. I also have a date slider, so a user can go back in time and view the output earlier in the year. I am pretty new to GEE, so my approach to changing the date, while not elegant, does work. On a change in choice with the date slider, all map layers are removed and then the new images are displayed.

Well, now, I would like to give the user some control over the colormap (for example, setting the maximum value) for some layers. No problem, I have added sliders for this, and I can grab the newly selected max value.

Here is where I am stuck. When the user uses the slider to select a new max value for the colormap, do I have to remove all layers and then re-display all of them, including the one changed one? I do not seem able to figure out how to just 'refresh' one layer.

The code below does not really work as intended, and I'm not sure why.

```
var now = Date.now();
var end = ee.Date(now).advance(-7, "month")
var tmp=end.format("YYYY_MM_dd").getInfo();
var uri_wy_hs = 'gs://cso_test_upload/wy_domain/snod_wo_assim/' + tmp + '_snod_wo_assim.tif';
var wy_hs = ee.Image.loadGeoTIFF(uri_wy_hs);
var uri_wy_swe = 'gs://cso_test_upload/wy_domain/swed_wo_assim/' + tmp + '_swed_wo_assim.tif';
var wy_swe = ee.Image.loadGeoTIFF(uri_wy_swe);

// Establish some color palette stuff
var palettes = require('users/gena/packages:palettes'); //brewermap and other colors...
var palette = palettes.cmocean.Thermal[7]; //use this for the CSO snow output (SWE) and density
var visparams = {min: 0, max:2, bands:['B0'], palette:palette}; //limits in meters - for swe
var visparams_hs = {min: 0, max:4, bands:['B0'], palette:palette}; //limits in meters - for hs
var vis = {min: 0, max: 2.0, palette: palette};
var vis_hs = {min: 0, max: 4.0, palette: palette};


// add test cso images

Map.addLayer(wy_hs,visparams_hs,'CSO Hs');
Map.addLayer(wy_swe,visparams,'CSO SWE')

/* Create UI Panels */
var panel = ui.Panel({style: {width:'25%'}});
ui.root.insert(0,panel);

var hspanel = ui.Panel({layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'),style: {width: '100%'}});
panel.add(hspanel)

var hslabel = ui.Label('Hs (m)',{textDecoration: 'underline', fontSize: '12px', margin: '10px 5px'});
hspanel.add(hslabel);
var hsslider = ui.Slider({
  min: 0, 
  max: 4, 
  value: 2, 
  step: 0.1, 
  style: {stretch: 'horizontal'},
  onChange: updatehslayer
});
hspanel.add(hsslider); 

var swepanel = ui.Panel({layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'),style: {width: '100%'}});
panel.add(swepanel)

var swelabel = ui.Label('swe (m)',{textDecoration: 'underline', fontSize: '12px', margin: '10px 5px'});
swepanel.add(swelabel);
var sweslider = ui.Slider({
  min: 0, 
  max: 2, 
  value: 1, 
  step: 0.1, 
  style: {stretch: 'horizontal'},
  onChange: updateswelayer
});
swepanel.add(sweslider); 


function updatehslayer(value){
  var hsmax = hsslider.getValue();
  var visparams_hs = {min: 0, max:hsmax, bands:['B0'], palette:palette};
  Map.layers().reset([wy_hs]);
  Map.addLayer(wy_hs,visparams_hs,'CSO Hs')
  
}

function updateswelayer(value){
  var swemax = sweslider.getValue();
  var visparams = {min: 0, max:swemax, bands:['B0'], palette:palette};
  Map.layers().reset([wy_swe]);
  Map.addLayer(wy_swe,visparams,'CSO swe')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the appropriate index in the `Map.layers()` list to a new layer with the updated visualization parameters. To see which is the appropriate index, you can `print(Map.layers)`; this order should be the same as that in which you added your layers.

Your code was pretty close, see below.

```
var now = Date.now();
var end = ee.Date(now).advance(-7, "month")
var tmp=end.format("YYYY_MM_dd").getInfo();
var uri_wy_hs = 'gs://cso_test_upload/wy_domain/snod_wo_assim/' + tmp + '_snod_wo_assim.tif';
var wy_hs = ee.Image.loadGeoTIFF(uri_wy_hs);
var uri_wy_swe = 'gs://cso_test_upload/wy_domain/swed_wo_assim/' + tmp + '_swed_wo_assim.tif';
var wy_swe = ee.Image.loadGeoTIFF(uri_wy_swe);

// Establish some color palette stuff
var palettes = require('users/gena/packages:palettes'); //brewermap and other colors...
var palette = palettes.cmocean.Thermal[7]; //use this for the CSO snow output (SWE) and density
var visparams = {min: 0, max:2, bands:['B0'], palette:palette}; //limits in meters - for swe
var visparams_hs = {min: 0, max:4, bands:['B0'], palette:palette}; //limits in meters - for hs
var vis = {min: 0, max: 2.0, palette: palette};
var vis_hs = {min: 0, max: 4.0, palette: palette};


// add test cso images

Map.addLayer(wy_hs,visparams_hs,'CSO Hs');
Map.addLayer(wy_swe,visparams,'CSO SWE')

/* Create UI Panels */
var panel = ui.Panel({style: {width:'25%'}});
ui.root.insert(0,panel);

var hspanel = ui.Panel({layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'),style: {width: '100%'}});
panel.add(hspanel)

var hslabel = ui.Label('Hs (m)',{textDecoration: 'underline', fontSize: '12px', margin: '10px 5px'});
hspanel.add(hslabel);
var hsslider = ui.Slider({
  min: 0, 
  max: 4, 
  value: 2, 
  step: 0.1, 
  style: {stretch: 'horizontal'},
  onChange: updatehslayer
});
hspanel.add(hsslider); 

var swepanel = ui.Panel({layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'),style: {width: '100%'}});
panel.add(swepanel)

var swelabel = ui.Label('swe (m)',{textDecoration: 'underline', fontSize: '12px', margin: '10px 5px'});
swepanel.add(swelabel);
var sweslider = ui.Slider({
  min: 0, 
  max: 2, 
  value: 1, 
  step: 0.1, 
  style: {stretch: 'horizontal'},
  onChange: updateswelayer
});
swepanel.add(sweslider); 


function updatehslayer(value){
  var hsmax = hsslider.getValue();
  var visparams_hs = {min: 0, max:hsmax, bands:['B0'], palette:palette};
  // Map.layers().reset([wy_hs]);
  // Map.addLayer(wy_hs,visparams_hs,'CSO Hs')
  
  
  Map.layers().set(0, ui.Map.Layer(wy_hs, visparams_hs,'CSO Hs'));
  
}

function updateswelayer(value){
  var swemax = sweslider.getValue();
  var visparams = {min: 0, max:swemax, bands:['B0'], palette:palette};
  //Map.layers().reset([wy_swe]);
  //Map.addLayer(wy_swe,visparams,'CSO swe')
  
  Map.layers().set(1, ui.Map.Layer(wy_swe, visparams,'CSO SWE'));
}

print(Map.layers())
```

Your project looks interesting! Hope this helps!